# Oracle ADF: Cannot convert 1 of type class java.math.BigDecimal to class oracle.jbo.domain.Number

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

This question look stupid but not realy.
Cannot convert 1 of type class java.math.BigDecimal to class oracle.jbo.domain.Number

How to convert

1. `oracle.jbo.domain.Number into java.math.BigDecimal`
2. `java.math.BigDecimal into oracle.jbo.domain.Number`

I get the Answer number one:

```
 oracle.jbo.domain.Number value = (Number)valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();
 java.math.BigDecimal costOfBuildingValue = value.bigDecimalValue();
```

Number two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `String` representation of the number in both ways:

```
oracle.jbo.domain.Number number = new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(12345);
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(number.toString());
```

and vice-versa:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(1241241);
oracle.jbo.domain.Number number = new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(bigDecimal.toString());
```

Even better, if you checkout the javadoc, you will see that there's a [`Number(BigDecimal bigDecimal)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e10655/oracle/jbo/domain/Number.html#Number(java.math.BigDecimal)) constructor:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(1241241);
oracle.jbo.domain.Number number = new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(bigDecimal);
```

---

† <sup>Note that I'm using the fully-qualified class name of `oracle.jbo.domain.Number` to avoid confusion with the `java.lang.Number` interface.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `Number` as follows:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(...);
Number costOfBuildingNumber = new Number(value);
```